# How can I open secret doors in alien bases?

Tags: xenonauts

The mission briefing for the alien base tells me that there are hidden doors that I can use .

[image]

I took over the Command Room, revealing the entire map of the alien base. It's pretty clear where all the secret doors are, but I can't seem to use them. No door icon appears when hovering the cursor over that wall section, and I also can't simply tell my guy to walk into the secret corridor. How do I use them?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After asking the question, it occurred to me that I should try free-targeting that section of wall. You can indeed blast a hole in it, allowing access to the corridor. I don't know if there are any other ways to get it open.

Comment: grenade the door, it will open.